# Gnome terminal transparent background shows desktop

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and I have the same problem I've always had after an installation/upgrade: the terminal's transparent background shows the desktop (not the window that is behind it).  I've seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74114/how-to-make-terminal-semi-transparent).

Most of the time,

```
gconftool-2 -s '/apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager' --type bool true
```

will get it to work, but this is not the case anymore.  I've also tried `compiz --replace` which *does* work, but then screws a lot of other stuff up and makes things pretty unusable.

Is there anything else I can do to

```
$ gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.6.2
```

Comment: I suppose it may depend on your graphics card, but I suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen is there a canonical spot I can report the bug so that something will be done about it?

Comment: Yes - http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: I find this behavior desirable wish I had the steps to reproduce this "bug" as default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.metacity compositing-manager true
```

And then adjust the transparency settings in the profile preferences.